# DataSet validation in ColumnChanging event

Tags: c#, ado.net

In my partial class containing the DataSet event I have the following:

```
protected override void OnColumnChanging(System.Data.DataColumnChangeEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Column.ColumnName)
    {
        case "ColumnA":
        {
            int value = GetValue(e.ProposedValue.ToString());

            if (value == -1)
            {
                e.Row.SetColumnError("ColumnA", string.Format("ColumnA could not map [{0}] to a valid value", e.ProposedValue));
                //e.ProposedValue = "";
           }

           break;
       }

       base.OnColumnChanging(e);
}
```

When I check for errors and get the column errors for my rows I see the appropriate message when GetValue(...) returns -1.  I also see that the column in that has the bad data still contains that bad value.  I was under the impression that calling SetColumnError(...) would reject the change made to that column (ColumnA) as per: [How to: Validate Data During Column Changes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f7ey06d%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

> Reject the proposed value by setting the column error (SetColumnError)
>   from within the column-changing event handler.

So when I try to do something like the following:

```
TypedDataSet set = new TypedDataSet();
TypedDataTable.TypedDataRow row = set.TypedDataTable.NewRow();
row.ColumnA = "Bad Data";
set.TypedDataTable.AddTypedDataRow(row);
```

I'll see the validation code execute, but the value of ColumnA retains: "Bad Data".  If I go as far as setting e.ProposedValue = null I can see the value change.

**Update**

Add event handlers for either RowsChanging or ColumnsChanging also produce similar results.

```
public override void BeginInit()
{
    base.BeginInit();
    TypedRowChanging += new TypedRowChangeEventHandler(TypedDataTable_TypedRowChanging);
    ColumnChanging += new DataColumnChangeEventHandler(TypedDataTable_ColumnChanging);
}
```

Code in both of the event handlers is trivial and will call e.Row.SetColumnError("ColumnA", "some error").  So my original question remains:

**What should be happening the in case where a column error is set on a column?** Should it retain value, become null, 42?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much testing and work I've come to the conclusion that the column retains the value when a column error is set on a specific column.  My current solution is to check for errors on the entire DataSet and then proceed to aggregate those errors into a format for error handling

```
TypedDataSet set = new TypedDataSet();
TypedDataTable.TypedDataRow row = set.TypedDataTable.NewRow();
row.ColumnA = "Bad Data";
set.TypedDataTable.AddTypedDataRow(row);

// At this point the DataSet has column errors and can be checked for...
if (set.HasErrors)
{
    // Build some error string container here
    TypedDataSet.TypedDataRow row = tempSet.TypedDataTable.Single();

    var errors = from column in row.GetColumnsInError()
                 select row.GetColumnError(column);

    foreach (var error in errors)
    {
        // Add to error container here
    }
}
```

After this I check if my error container has any data in it.  I suppose it makes sense for the column to retain value so that the programmer has access to that value and can include that it in the call to SetColumnError(...).

Answer (score 0):

According to the doc you linked, you don't want to override OnColumnChanged - you want to add an eventhandler for the ColumnChanged event. Try using the sample code provided there for a starting point.

Comment: It's a nice thought, but both the OnColumnChanging/ColumnChange events are being executed with similar functionality and results.  I ended up on OnColumnChanging first because I went with typing out override to see what the partial class provided before finding the documentation about adding an event handler to ColumnChanged.